# Best way to override scss files?

Tags: theme, css, scss

When you're overidding css, specifically scss in a theme, is it better to copy all the scss files to the new theme and make edits in those, 
or create just one new custom scss file that contains the overrides?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only need to create the files for the styles/modules you intend to overwrite, but I wouldn't throw them all into one file.

They should get compiled by Magento anyways, and having them isolated should make maintaining them a bit easier for you.